# Using python library "Requests" with Tor bridges

Tags: python, python-requests, tor

I'm fiddling around with Python and some scraping with the library Request ([ref](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)) and Tor ([ref](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tor)). I'm putting the two things together like [this](https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/using-tor-with-the-python-request-library-79015b2606cb).

Everything seems to work fine, but I stumbled upon some websites that recognise that I'm using Tor and will return no content even though the content is present (I can verify that by doing the same thing without using Tor proxy).

With the normal Tor browser I would use Tor bridges to solve the problem but I don't know how to apply the same principle with Python and Requests. Is there a way to integrate both things? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: As far as I can gather from the manuals it works nearly identical. The only difference is that you have to specify the bridge when starting `tor`: https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#Bridge

Comment: show your Torrc file

Comment: which os you use?? see you need to configure tor in your system.  ```/etc/tor/torrc``` you can configure tor from **torrc** file